# How can I get a value from a specified position in an array list (processing)?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, get, processing

I need to get a value from an array list. The objects in the list stores some values in variables (x- and y-coordinates).

I tried to use the get()-function but it only returns a string like this: linkTrackerTest$Object@20e76e47.

In addition I tried thinks like objects.get(0(x)) but nothing worked yet.

Could anybody help me with this?

Thank in advance :-)

Comment: Have you tried `objects.get(0).x `?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that shows the behavior in as few lines as possible? Note that this should not be your whole sketch. It should be a small example that we can copy and paste to see the problem on our own computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that odd string because its returning the memory address of the data instead of the data itself because java is implicitly calling a `toString()`.

Try:

`yourObject x = list.get(i);`

or

`int x = list.get(i).xValue; / int y = list.get(i).yValue;`

or just override the `toString()` completely by writing your own

Comment: That is not the memory address of the Object. Please format the code properly.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you get it's totally normal.

Since I guess you are trying to print the Object returned by `get`, and since you have not provided an `Override` for the `Object`'s `toString()` method, the best Java can do is to print the so called *identity hashcode* - "kinda of the memory address" of it.

Try adding the following as a member of your class:

```
         @Override
        public String toString() {
            return x+" "+y;
        }
```

This way then you try to print your class, Java will automatically call the provided `toString()`

- The problem here is not in the way you access an element of an `ArrayList`, the `get` method all you need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you have a list of Objects
you can get values you are looking for with a getter method in your Object class

```
public class Obj {

     private int x;
     private int y;

     // constructor in which x, y values are given 
     public Obj(int x_val, int y_val) {
          this.x = x_val;
          this.y = y_val;
     }

     // getter
     public int get_x() {
          return this.x;
     }

     public int get_y() {
          return this.y;
     }



 public static void main(String[] args) {

      List<Obj> Obj_Lst = new ArrayList<Obj>();

      // adding objects to list
      Obj_Lst.add(new Obj(1,6));
      Obj_Lst.add(new Obj(2,5));
      Obj_Lst.add(new Obj(3,4));

      // getting values from object
      System.out.println(Obj_Lst.get(0).get_x());

 }

}
```

Output

1